# How would i pause before continuing waves in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im making an enemy wave - based game and it works fine, but i want to make it so before it continues on to the next wave, the player has to press a key to let the game know they're ready, the reason i want to do this is because i want to implement a shop to purchase upgrades after waves, here is my wave script:

SpawnManager.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Wave
{
    public int EnemiesPerWave;
    public GameObject Enemy;
}

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Wave[] Waves; // class to hold information per wave
    public Transform[] SpawnPoints;
    public float TimeBetweenEnemies = 2f;

    private int _totalEnemiesInCurrentWave;
    private int _enemiesInWaveLeft;
    private int _spawnedEnemies;

    private int _currentWave;
    private int _totalWaves;

    void Start ()
    {
        _currentWave = -1; // avoid off by 1
        _totalWaves = Waves.Length - 1; // adjust, because we're using 0 index

        StartNextWave();
    }

    void StartNextWave()
    {
        _currentWave++;

        // win
        if (_currentWave > _totalWaves)
        {
            return;
        }

        _totalEnemiesInCurrentWave = Waves[_currentWave].EnemiesPerWave;
        _enemiesInWaveLeft = 0;
        _spawnedEnemies = 0;

        StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemies());
    }

    // Coroutine to spawn all of our enemies
    IEnumerator SpawnEnemies()
    {
        GameObject enemy = Waves[_currentWave].Enemy;
        while (_spawnedEnemies < _totalEnemiesInCurrentWave)
        {
            _spawnedEnemies++;
            _enemiesInWaveLeft++;

            int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, SpawnPoints.Length);

            // Create an instance of the enemy prefab at the randomly selected spawn point's 
            // position and rotation.
            Instantiate(enemy, SpawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, 
                             SpawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeBetweenEnemies);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
    
    // called by an enemy when they're defeated
    public void EnemyDefeated()
    {
        _enemiesInWaveLeft--;
        
        // We start the next wave once we have spawned and defeated them all
        if (_enemiesInWaveLeft == 0 && _spawnedEnemies == _totalEnemiesInCurrentWave)
        {
            StartNextWave();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a Boolean like `waitForKey=true`, then in something like Update:

```
if( waitForKey && Input.GetKeyDown("space") ) {
    waitForKey=false;
    StartNextWave();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to a button input in the `Update` function.

```
void Update() 
{
    if (_enemiesInWaveLeft <= 0 && InputGetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        StartNewWave();
    }
}
```

This will cause the wave to spawn when there are no enemies left and `Space` is pressed down. You will need to add some UI separately to this to give the player some feedback as to when it is Ok to press the `Space` Button.

Also remove the StartNextWave from your `EnemyDefeated` funciton. That can be used to enable and disable UI for the player to let them know to press a button to continue.